# How would I fix "Illegal start of expression"?

Tags: java

I am getting `Illegal start of expression` when I run the following code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParadiseInfo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double price;
        double discount;
        double savings;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter cutoff price for discount >> ");
        price = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter discount rate as a whole number >> ");
        discount = keyboard.nextDouble();
        displayInfo();

        public static double computeDiscountInfo(double price, double discountRate) {
            double savings;
            savings = price * discountRate / 100;
            return savings;
        }
        savings = computeDiscountInfo(price, discount);
    }

    public static void displayInfo() {
        System.out.println("Paradise Day Spa wants to pamper you.");
        System.out.println("We will make you look good.");
        System.out.println("Special this week on any service over" + price);
        System.out.println("Discount of " + discount + "percent");
        System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + savings);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can not have a method within a method. Move the **computeDiscountInfo()** method under the **main()** method code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not Allowed:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double price;
    double discount;
    double savings;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter cutoff price for discount >> ");
    price = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter discount rate as a whole number >> ");
    discount = keyboard.nextDouble();
    displayInfo();
        // ***  This method can not be here!
        public static double computeDiscountInfo(double price, double discountRate) {
            double savings;
            savings = price * discountRate / 100;
            return saings;
        }
        // ***
    savings = computeDiscountInfo(price, discount);
}
```

**This is allowed:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double price;
    double discount;
    double savings;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter cutoff price for discount >> ");
    price = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter discount rate as a whole number >> ");
    discount = keyboard.nextDouble();
    displayInfo();
    savings = computeDiscountInfo(price, discount);
}

public static double computeDiscountInfo(double price, double discountRate) {
    double savings;
    savings = price * discountRate / 100;
    return saings;
}
```

**

> **EDIT: Your other problem according to you comments:**

As per your comments, you are having this issue because the variables `price`, `discount`, and `savings` are not available to the ***displayInfo()*** method. They are out of scope. One of two things you can do here. Add these variables as parameters to that method:

```
public static void displayInfo(double price, double discount, double savings) {
    System.out.println("Paradise Day Spa wants to pamper you.");
    System.out.println("We will make you look good.");
    System.out.println("Special this week on any service over" + price);
    System.out.println("Discount of " + discount + "percent");
    System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + savings);
}
```

**OR** since you utilize these variables in all your class methods, make those variables Class Member Variables so that scope will be **global** to the entire class, for example:

```
public class MyClassWhateverItsCalled {

    private static double price = 0.0d;
    private static double discount = 0.0d;
    private static double savings  = 0.0d;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter cutoff price for discount >> ");
        this.price = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter discount rate as a whole number >> ");
        this.discount = keyboard.nextDouble();
        this.savings = computeDiscountInfo();
        displayInfo();
    }

    public static void computeDiscountInfo() {
        this.savings = this.price * this.discountRate / 100;
    }

    public static void displayInfo() {
        System.out.println("Paradise Day Spa wants to pamper you.");
        System.out.println("We will make you look good.");
        System.out.println("Special this week on any service over $" + this.price);
        System.out.println("Discount of " + this.discount + "%");
        System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + this.savings);
    }
}
```

Something like that....

To eliminate the need for everything to be static you can do this (main() needs to remain static):

```
public class MyClassWhateverItsCalled {

    private double price = 0.0d;
    private double discount = 0.0d;
    private double savings  = 0.0d;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClassWhateverItsCalled().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter cutoff price for discount >> ");
        this.price = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter discount rate as a whole number >> ");
        this.discount = keyboard.nextDouble();
        this.savings = computeDiscountInfo();
        displayInfo();       
    } 

    public void computeDiscountInfo() {
        this.savings = this.price * this.discountRate / 100;
    }

    public void displayInfo() {
        System.out.println("Paradise Day Spa wants to pamper you.");
        System.out.println("We will make you look good.");
        System.out.println("Special this week on any service over $" + this.price);
        System.out.println("Discount of " + this.discount + "%");
        System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + this.savings);
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the “Illegal start of expression"!
But now I'm pulling "Can't find symbol" on line 29,30,31
Saying it can't find price, saving, or discount

Comment: And which are lines: `29,30,31`? Make sure your variables are in scope

Comment: AH! I'm sorry I should have stated what the lines were! They are:

   public static void displayInfo()
      {
      System.out.println("Paradise Day Spa wants to pamper you.");
      System.out.println("We will make you look good.");
    29 System.out.println("Special this week on any service over" + price);
    30 System.out.println("Discount of " + discount + "percent");
    31  System.out.println("That's a savings of at least $" + savings);
      }

This is all at the very end of the code

Comment: Because the variables `price`, `discount`, and `savings` are not available to the ***displayInfo()*** method. They are out of scope. One of two things you can do here. Add these variables as parameters to that method OR since you utilize these variables in all your class methods, make those variables Class Member Variables so that scope will be global to the entire class.

Comment: @DrHexDex, See the EDIT in the posted answer